# How to config the project.properties in Sonar-scanner?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am a rookie in SonarQube.
I want to scan the source code in GitHub by command line and push the result as comments to GitHub. I found some documents in SonarDoc, there is an example.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin
I tried to  config like that, but failed.

**Could please tell to how to config this?**

```
sonar.projectKey=Demo
sonar.projectName=PluginDemo
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.analysis.mode=preview
sonar.github.repository=githuang2016/PluginDemo
sonar.github.oauth=aa2924572c5c45271287d0934826f0c28b2e66dd
sonar.github.endpoint=https://api.github.com
sonar.host.url=http://10.20.34.69:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

Error message:

> Access to the secured property 'sonar.mantis.login.secured' is not possible in issues mode. The SonarQube plugin which requires this property must be deactivated in issues mode.

Comment: failed how? What, if any, were the error messages?

Comment: Error Messages:Access to the secured property 'sonar.mantis.login.secured' is not possible in issues mode. The SonarQube plugin which requires this property must be deactivated in issues mode.
And i want to ask where i can find the sonar.github.pullRequest and the  $SONARQUBE_ACCESS_TOKEN? Or if you can provide an example to me ? Thanks.

Comment: That's a whole new question @Huang. Open a new question here or go to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) to ask it. Also, it would help to give your SonarQube version - in the question itself.